# Comparing MatchCharAt to StringBuilder?

Tags: java

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    int length=0;
    int MaxNumber=100;
    StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();



    do {
        if (PasswordGenerator.matchLength (length))
            System.out.println("The length of the character is " + length);
        length++;
    } while (length < MaxNumber);

    do {
        if (PasswordGenerator.matchCharAt (password))
            System.out.println("The password is " + password);
    } while (  );



}
}
```

My code is supposed to find the length of a given password, which it already does. And then the next step is supposed to determine the password, by appending each individual character with Stringbuilder.

But anyways I keep getting an error that

> method matchCharAt in class PasswordGenerator cannot be applied to given types:
>   Required: char, int
>   Found: StringBuilder
>   Reason: Actual and formal argument lists differ in length*

Any help would be awesome!

P.S. Password Generator is a "Made up" class, if you need documentation I can post it.

Comment: Can you post `PasswordGenerator.matchCharAt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code says clearly, you are using wrong parameter:

```
method matchCharAt in class PasswordGenerator cannot be applied to given types: Required: char, int Found: StringBuilder Reason: Actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

You need to provide two parameter: First one `char`, second a `int`

This question sounds and smells like homework. If so: Please tag it as homework.

Comment: ah, I didn't know you were suppose to tag your homework on Stack overflow. Thank you for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder is similar to a string, but not the same. It buffers a length so that you can concatenate without creating a bunch of extra strings (since strings are immutable).

It doesn't look like you're actually using the StringBuilder anywhere in that method, I recommend you define it inside the `PasswordGenerator.matchCharAt()` method and return a full password string.

We would need the documentation to PasswordGenerator to get any more specific within the constraints of your assignment.